# how to insert a row with default value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

after form submission, the data is stored in database. This is the query i already have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registered_users` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`date_birth` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`postal_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`place` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`school_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`email` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
`tel` varchar(55) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is how i insert the data into the DB:

Now i want to insert a new row in the DB which can have only 2 values: "active" or "inactive" for each user. Default on "inactive". That should be inserted automatically for each user after submit. How can i do that?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: lets hope the user's first name isn't something like bob")';drop table registered_users;//

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a table in a mysql db you can specify a default value for attributes. So if you want a boolean "active" / "inactive" flag you might want to try adding an active attribute to your table. See the added last column here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registered_users` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`date_birth` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`postal_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`place` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`school_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`email` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
`tel` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
`active` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Ref.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html